# Azure - Disable VM Agent to prevent root password modification

Tags: azure, configuration, passwords, virtual-machine

I am currently creating an Azure application for the marketplace and I want to forbid the user to connect to the VM to avoid any modification of the configuration of the VM.

So, to do that, I want to block the update of the root password the user set when creating the VM. I think it is aVM agent that is updating the root password on the VM with the one the user set.

Is there any way to prevent this password update?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want users reset password from Azure portal?

Comment: Yes and I also want to forbid the user to do a sudo command (like sudo su) that would give him root rights

Comment: For now, we can't remove sudo from that user, as a workaround, we can create a new user to access this VM, so this new user will not have the password for root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the customer of my application to connect on the VM hosting my application with the user he created when instantiating it, I have created a script which delete this user from the sudoers user :

- `` USER=`getent group sudo | cut -d: -f4` ``
- `sudo deluser $USER sudo`
- `sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`
- `sudo gpasswd -d $USER adm`

This way the user has not the possibility to become root and to alter the applications running on the VM

Answer (score 0):

You can not select value "root" for user when provisioning linux vm in Azure.

Comment: Yes, I know that, what I want to do is to forbid the user to get root rights :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your explanation, you want to prevent this password update from Azure portal.

If I understand it correctly, I think disable VM Agent is a way to prevent root password modification, but it is dangerous, if there are somethings wrong with your VM, we can't use Azure VM agent to do some troubleshoot.

As a workaround, we can use Role-Based Access control (**RBAC**) to manage access to your Azure subscription resources. More information about RBAC, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure).

Also, we can set resource **Locks** to **Read-only**, then we can't change password via Azure portal.

[image]
[image]

More information about **Lock resources to prevent unexpected changes**, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources).

Comment: This lock is to be applied on the image for which I have to get the SAS, am I correct? Also, I guess if I update the /etc/sudoers.d/waagent file, I could remove the sudo rights for the user, right?

Comment: No, this lock just can't reset password via Azure portal. if you want to remove the sudo rights for the user, you can add another user account to this VM, and let others connect to this VM use new user accounts. for now, we can't remove the rights for the user.

Comment: As a workaround, we can create a new user, `out of sudu group`. In this way, this user can't run sudo to get the root permission.

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this did not fulfill my expectations. I have created a script which delete the user created when someone instantiate my application from the sudoer conf file : `USER=\`getent group sudo | cut -d: -f4\`` then `sudo deluser $USER sudo` then `sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` and finally `sudo gpasswd -d $USER adm`. This way the user has not the possibility to become root and to alter the applications running on the VM

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks for your share:)